# Why can I abstract override an abstract method?

Tags: c#

I have an abstract base class:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    virtual void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        //Do Some Stuff
    }

    abstract void DoSomeCrazyStuff();
}
```

And another abstract class derived from that:

```
abstract class Bar : Foo
{
    abstract override void DoSomeStuff();

    abstract override void DoSomeCrazyStuff();
}
```

I understand why you'd want to abstract override `DoSomeStuff()` - it will require an new implementation for further derived classes.  But I can't figure out why you would want to abstract override `DoSomeCrazyStuff()`.  As far as I can tell, it's redundant - I'm pretty sure removing it would have zero negative impact.

Is there some use case where abstract override on an abstract does something useful?  If not, why isn't there a compiler warning informing me that what I've wrote does nothing?

Comment: this link might help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: This falls in the category of "because the spec says so."

Comment: Looks like a good feature request for Roslyn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can I abstract override an abstract method?

For starters, there's no practical reason for preventing it.  If it produced a compiler error, all that would do is make classes more brittle.  For example:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    virtual void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        //Do Some Stuff
    }
}

abstract class Bar : Foo
{
    abstract override void DoSomeStuff();
}
```

If abstract override on abstract was illegal, changing DoSomeStuff on Foo to abstract would now prevent Bar from compiling.  The abstract override is redundant, but there's no potential negative side effects, so the compiler is okay with this.

---

> Why isn't there a compiler warning informing me that what I've wrote does nothing?

The compiler produces warnings for certain things that represent risk: non-explicit method hiding, unreachable code, using obsolete methods, etc.  The only "problem" an unnecessary abstract override could indicate is that the code was not efficiently written.  That's not something the compiler cares about.

---

> Is there some use case where abstract override on an abstract does something useful?

Not functionally.  However, there are a few use cases where you might intentionally do so:

- To improve the "readability" of the code.  Having the redundant abstract override would serve as a reminder that the method is abstract.
- If future changes to the base class include providing a virtual implementation, you can preemptively prevent some classes from accessing that base class.
- If the abstract override is redundant because the base class was changed from a virtual implementation to abstract, it can safely be left alone.

Answer (score 2):

By explicitly `abstract override`ing it in `Bar` you make sure it's going to be seen as abstract by `Bar`s descendents even though in the future in `Foo` it may be changed into a non-abstract one. Despite such change, `Bar`s descendants will work with the same contract.

Comment: I see the practical value in that, but isn't it a violation of Liskov Substitution? Any methods that operate on `Foo`'s and expect a concrete `DoSomeCrazyStuff` would break when passed a `Bar`.

Comment: @AustinMullins Bar and DoSomeCrazyStuff are still abstract, so nothing will be operating on a Bar, but rather a concrete class that will not compile without an implementation of all the abstract methods.

Comment: @OndrejTucny You don't need the additional abstract override to protect against contract changes, existing overrides of `Bar` would still override the virtual implementation.  It is preemptively preventing descendants of `Bar` written AFTER `Foo`s is changed to be virtual from accessing the base implementation.  Why prevent access to a method that hasn't been written?  Why not save that decision until the method is actually written?